# How to understand the Uniswap V3 swap fee calculation

Tags: solidity, swap

i read the whitepaper and the code about uniswapv3. but i am still confused about uni-v3 swap fee calculation.

i can‘t understand  3 formula

> `qustion1` cant understand Tick struct field feeGrowthOutside(0/1)X128

```
   
    struct Info {

        uint256 feeGrowthOutside0X128;
        uint256 feeGrowthOutside1X128;

    }
```

which at whitepaper is  [image]

if swap cross it will be

[image]

> `question2` cant understand above tick i and below tick i formula

which at whitepaper is
[image]

i know at uniswapv3 code. when add/remove liquidity will calculate fee owned because liqudity is discrete。 but i really dont konw what 3 formula mean although i tried the fee  distribution result is right

Answer (score 0):

`feeGrowthOutside` tracks how much fee has grown "outside" the tick. In case of the price goes past the tick lower bound from left to right, it is how much fee growth when the price was on the left side of the bound. Noted that, once the price goes past to the right side of the lower bound, the fee earned on its left side will stay the same, and hence, `f_o` will then be constant.

`f_g` or `feeGrowthGlobal`, will still growing no matter the current price is on the left, right side, or inside of the tick, hence the fee earned for the right side of the lower bound of the tick, in this case, is `f_g` - `f_o`.